# It is adj that... v.s. It is adj to do

Tags: to-infinitive, paraphrasing

I believe that "It is natural that parents love their children." can be rewritten as "It is natural for parents to love their children."  Is this always the case?

- A1) It is dangerous for you to drive when you are drunk.
- B1) It is nice of Bob to have made a cake for us.

Can they be rewritten as

- A2) It is dangerous that you drive when you are drunk.
- B2) It is nice that Bob made a cake for us.

I somehow feel awkward with A2 and B2, but I don't know why.  Are they all correct?

Answer (score 1):

They are grammatical and broadly similar in meaning, and most native speakers would accept either as meaning that the A statements mean that I should not drive when I am drunk (because danger would arise) and the B statements mean that Bob's cake gives pleasure. However, it could be said that A1 and B1 focus on the persons involved (my dangerous choice, Bob's kindness) while A2 and B2 focus on the danger and pleasure.